# Windows Forms: Modeless ShowDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

What could be the reason, that a winforms-form, which is opened with ShowDialog() (no parameters), appears modeless (I can still select the parent window)? Maybe it has something to do with a backgroundworker in the parent window? When I use `this` as parameter I get a cross thread exception.

Comment: Is the currently active window still around when the form is opened?

Comment: could you provide a little more information, show some code, ... usually that should not happen.

Comment: What do you mean "appears non-modal"?

Comment: I have solved the problem with a workaround!

Answer (score 2):

Do you open it from thread that owns main window ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

The only possible way that I can think of having a 'modeful' ShowDialog is if you're opening from a `BackgroundWorker`. The fact that references to `this` give you cross thread exceptions is a kind of hint that you're doing something wrong...